# Java BigInteger variable

Tags: java

In my code I have to check if the string is a valid number so I do the following

```
try{
    new BigIntger(numericString);

}catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
  throw NumberFormatException;
}
```

I know its sort of hack/workaround whatever you say about it, but what I wanted to know is

`new BigIntger(numericString)` which must be creating the object in heap what if I assign this value to a variable `BigInteger val = new BigIntger(numericString)` where is the variable `val` stored ?

It sounds very basic but I am not able to imagine the difference between the two.

Comment: Read more about the Basic of Java. In first case object is created but there is no reference so you can't get it again. It's lost in the heap and after sometime collected by GC to destroy it. **It's just like a balloon that don't have any thread to keep it with you and it's lost in the sky.**

Comment: This is not specific to BigIntegers.  You first need to understand the difference between objects and variables.

Comment: @Braj That was one awesome expalnation!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val` is only a reference to the object itself, the object is stored in the heap and the pointer is stored in the stack.

the actual value of `val` in the stack is an address of the object in the hep.

the `new` reserved word in java, says that a reference will be returned, in the first case you just dont save it so the object is as usual created in the stack but probably will get collected in a short while. in the second case, while `val` is still in the stack and pointing to that object, it will stay in the heap